# How to force iPython to use an older version of Python?

Tags: python, version, backwards-compatibility, ipython

I have to use a very outdated version of python (2.4) at work, so I'd like to tell ipython to use that version instead of the default one on the system. How can I do that?

( I know [there is a dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308254/how-to-force-ipython-to-use-an-older-version-of-python), but the accepted answer doesn't work for me, because I only have one ipython on my system, and there are no other packages to install )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it using the other Python version's executable.

```
python2.9 setup.py install
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: The future is NOW!

Comment: And to get the future, add 0.2 to that version number :P

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly! (for 2.4 I had to take version 0.10, because they say the newer ones no longer support python 2.4)